# Typescript class member undefined - Compiler Flow correct?

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to typescript and I recently was writing a class. Unfortunately my editor (Visual Studio Code) bugs me about an error that I cannot comprehend. It says: "the object (foo) is possible undefined". But how?

Here is an example:

```
export class Foo {
    foo: string | undefined;
    constructor() {
        this.foo = "hello";
    }

    lengthOfFoo() {
        /*if (!this.foo) {
            return;
        }*/
        let len = this.foo.length; // <- error: the object (foo) is possible undefined
        return len;
    }
}
```

The error only goes away if I uncomment the check above, but because of the constructor function:

```
constructor() {
    this.foo = "hello";
}
```

this.foo cannot be undefined and the error should not arise in the first place if the flow is correct or am I wrong?

For explanation why I'm using this expression

```
foo: string | undefined;
```

This is just a simplified example. I was actually trying to use the Map Type which has a Map.get() function which can be undefined. Here the declaration of the Map Type:

```
interface Map<K, V> {
    clear(): void;
    delete(key: K): boolean;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: V, key: K, map: Map<K, V>) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
    get(key: K): V | undefined;
    has(key: K): boolean;
    set(key: K, value: V): this;
    readonly size: number;
}
```

and here the actual code:

```
export default class EventEmitter {
    listener: Map<string, Function[]> = new Map();
    foo: string | undefined = "hello";

    constructor() {
        this.listener = new Map();
        this.foo = "hello";

    }

    addListener(label: string, callback: Function) {
        this.listener.has(label) || this.listener.set(label, []);
        this.listener.get(label).push(callback); <- error: object is possible undefined
        this.foo.length; // <- error: object is possible undefined
    }

    removeListener(label: string, callback: Function) {

    }

    emit(label: string, ...args: any[]) {

    }
}
```

Who can explain to me why this error is happening and what would be the right way to implement the EventEmitter class?

Answer (score 5):

> this.foo cannot be undefined and the error should not arise in the first place if the flow is correct or am I wrong?

Certainly wrong. Someone can write this:

```
const f = new Foo();
f.foo = undefined;
f.lengthOfFoo();
```

Answer (score 0):

So looking at your snippet:

```
addListener(label: string, callback: Function) {
    this.listener.has(label) || this.listener.set(label, []);
    this.listener.get(label).push(callback); // <- error: object is possible undefined
    this.foo.length; // <- error: object is possible undefined
}
```

It appears that if the key you're trying to get from the map does not exist, you immediately set it to empty array. So you correctly infer that the key's value cannot be `undefined` on the next line.

But there's no way for typescript to know that, since in general maps can return undefined for any key you try to access. But since you, as the developer, know better, you can just use a non-null assertion `!` to silence the error.

```
addListener(label: string, callback: Function) {
    this.listener.has(label) || this.listener.set(label, []);
    this.listener.get(label)!.push(callback); // <- note the ! after get call
    this.foo.length; // <- error: object is possible undefined
}
```

Just be sure to use that operator with care, since you are overriding the type safety that typescript is attempting to provide.

In general, accessing the value for some key in a map can return undefined, *but in your specific case we can see that's not possible*, since we see that you set it on the line before that if it didn't exist. So in your case, using the `!` operator might be just what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Seems to be a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Rayans' reply, to fix this:

change your return statement from:
**this.foo.length;**

to

**Number(!!this.foo && this.foo.length);**